# Can we write both signs here?

Tags: trigonometry

$\sin(90^\circ+(A+B))=\cos(A+B)\\\sin(90^\circ-(A+B))=\cos(A+B)$

Can we write both signs here? Does it not cause any difference to the answer?

Comment: Yes, because $\cos(x)=\cos(-x)$ for all $x$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes , we can because
Let (A+B)=C

Sin(90-C) lies in 1st quadrant where sin is + and sin(90+C)lies in 2nd quadrant where sin is also +.So we can that both are correct but it may not happen every time.That given us cos(A+B).